# Webasyst: ошибка в шаблоне

Tags: javascript, smarty, webasyst

> Syntax Error in template
>   "/public_html/wa-apps/shop/plugins/filters/templates/frontendHead.html"
>   on line 2 "<script>loadEvents.push(function()
>   {window.jQuery.ui || document.write(unescape('%3Cscript
>   src="{$plugin_url}js/jquery-ui.core.slider.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))});</script>"
>   - Unexpected ".", expected one of: "}" , " " , ATTR (0)

Собственно, вот это место:

```
<script>loadEvents.push(function() {window.jQuery.ui || document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="{$plugin_url}js/jquery-ui.core.slider.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))});</script>
```

Не могу понять, что не так-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в смарти, чтобы не ругался. пришлось просто добавить пробелы перед `window` в :

```
<script>loadEvents.push(function() { window.jQuery.ui || document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="{$plugin_url}js/jquery-ui.core.slider.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))});</script>
<script>loadEvents.push(function() { window.jQuery.ui.slider || document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="{$wa_url}wa-content/js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.slider.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))});</script>
```